# parallel nested foreach loops

Tags: r, foreach, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to code a [nested](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.html) parallel foreach loop for a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, but the matrices aren't combining correctly. Sample code is below, the final matrix, mtx2, should be same dimensions as the original, mtx, but with some rows randomly altered. How should the matrix rows be combined?

I tried the foreach package directly, but same result - mtx2 combines the columns 5 times.

```
# library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 2  
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)  
registerDoParallel(cl)  

mtx <- matrix(data=rnorm(n=1e3*5,mean=0,sd=1),nrow=1e3,ncol=5)
mtx2 <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=1e3,ncol=5)

#basic for loop - slow for large number of rows
for(k in 1:nrow(mtx)){
  for(r in 1:5) {
    if(runif(n=1,min=0,max=1)>0.9){
      mtx2[k,] <- mtx[k,]*10
    }else{
      mtx2[k,] <- mtx[k,]
    }  
  }
}

#series version for de-bugging
mtx2 <-foreach(k=1:nrow(mtx),.combine="rbind") %do% {
  foreach(r=1:5,.combine="c") %do% {
    if(runif(n=1,min=0,max=1)>0.9){
      mtx[k,]*10
    }else{
      mtx[k,]
    }  
  }
}

#parallel version
mtx2 <-foreach(k=1:nrow(mtx),.combine="rbind") %:% {
  foreach(r=1:5,.combine="c") %dopar% {
    if(runif(n=1,min=0,max=1)>0.9){
      mtx[k,]*10
    }else{
      mtx[k,]
    }  
  }
}

mtx2 <- round(mtx2,2)
```

Comment: Perhaps using [foreach](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/foreach) directly rather than `doParallel` adapter, as your code eyeballs correct. Just a guess.

Comment: I get an error when trying the parallel version due to the `%:%` operator. Regardless, for each inner loop, you are returning the row of `mtx[k, ]` which is length 5. Since you are looping `r = 1:5`, it makes sense that that is returning something 25 in length (`5*5`). Perhaps you would instead want to summarize those results (e.g., `mean(mtx[k, ]) * 10`) or maybe it should be `mtx[k, r] * 10`

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried the foreach package directly, the code runs, but mtx2 is still has 25 columns - the result has been copied and combined 5 times as per r=1:5

Comment: Make sure you tag someone to make sure they see your response (e.g.`@Cole`). I looked at your revised code. Why do you loop `r in 1:5`? Only the last iteration is saved in the plain for loop.

Comment: @Cole that's how the MH algo works, it looks for a better solution in 5 or n attempts and only the last attempt needs to be saved. This code is just a simple version which codes the same way, but the result in this code is irrelevant.

Comment: I am not sure if this implements MH algo AFAIU. MCMC is somewhat recursive whereas this does not depend on previous results. This implementation could be simplified by replacing the inner loop with `if (runif(5)[5] > 0.9) {…}`. Regardless, the current parallel loops are going to get 25 results for each pass in the inner loop. If you are interested in the iterations, you could look at arrays or a list of matrices.

Comment: @Cole, this post isn't about MH or MCMC, it's about parallel loops. I only want to find a method of updating a matrix in a nested loop.

Comment: Updating a matrix in a parallelized loop is not really possible. Note the plain loop saves over the same result which wouldn’t be thread safe. This particular example is easy to be completely vectorized (e.g. using `runif(nrow(mtx)) > .9` to skip a loop.) Your example is a nice MRE but you may want to modify the question closer to what you are actually doing. See also https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/doFuture/issues/31

Comment: @Cole, thanks for the link. I'm going to be less ambitious and only run the outer loop in parallel so I can keep working. I'll leave the question up in case someone has a solution, unless the moderators prefer to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on comments, you can skip the loop by creating your logical comparison all at once. Here, we create `runif(nrow(mtx) * ncol(mtx))` but only take every 5th result to match up the OP inner loop of `for (r in 1:5) {...}`

The key point is that while the OP question of finding a method of updating a matrix in a nested parallel loop is not possible for this approach, refactoring code can sometimes provide significant performance gains.

```r
nr = 1e4
nc = 5
mtx <- matrix(data=rnorm(n=nr*nc,mean=0,sd=1),nrow=nr,ncol=nc)

set.seed(123L)
lgl = matrix(runif(n = nr * nc), ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)[, nc] > 0.9
mtx3 = sweep(mtx, 1L, 1 + 9 * lgl, FUN = '*')

all.equal(mtx2, mtx3) ##mtx2 was created with set.seed(123L)

# [1] TRUE
```

For 1 million rows this is significantly faster:

```
system.time({
  lgl = matrix(runif(n = nr * nc), ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)[, nc] > 0.9
  mtx3 = sweep(mtx, 1L, 1 + 9 * lgl, FUN = '*')
})

##    user  system elapsed 
##    0.27    0.00    0.27 

system.time({
  for(k in 1:nrow(mtx)){
    for(r in 1:5) {
      if(runif(n=1,min=0,max=1)>0.9){
        mtx2[k,] <- mtx[k,]*10
      }else{
        mtx2[k,] <- mtx[k,]
      }  
    }
  }
})

##    user  system elapsed 
##   14.09    0.03   14.12
```